# Gitlab Personal Access Token - where to keep the token for seamless clone / pull / push

Tags: git, gitlab

Can anyone tell where to put the Gitlab PAT - Personal Access Token?

Downloading git::https://gitlab.com/mycompany/myproject.git?ref=v0.0.1 - unable to download - I can't change the URL as its fixed in project repo.

I tried to set it in my git config --global
gitlab.accesstoken=abcdef1233TVHEPkNxyz

also as environment variable
TOKEN=abcdef1233TVHEPkNxyz
PRIVATE_TOKEN=abcdef1233TVHEPkNxyz

Any advice please?

Comment: Are you calling a Gitlab API? If so, the token is passed in `--header "Private-Token:  ${TOKEN}"`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically we need to:

1. Generate PAT https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens    [permissions as per requirement]
2. `git clone https://oauth2:abcdef1233TVHEPkNxyz@gitlab.com/mycompany/myproject.git?ref=v0.0.1`

However, if we can not change the url from: `git::https://gitlab.com/mycompany/myproject.git?ref=v0.0.1` to the above format or we want to avoid entering the token each time we clone a repo or use GitLab APIs, we need to do the following:

1. Setup a credential store, example on Ubuntu:

   ```
   `sudo apt-get install libsecret-1-0 libsecret-1-dev`
   `sudo make --directory=/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret`
   `git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret`
   ```
2. Git clone a http url:

   ```
   `git clone https://gitlab.com/mycompany/myproject.git?ref=v0.0.1`
   ```

when prompted for password use PAT instead. The PAT will be stored in the libsecret store for default 15 minutes. use `git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=1800'` to change the timeout duration.

Refer: https://www.softwaredeveloper.blog/git-credential-storage-libsecret

Comment: `https://oauth2:abcdef1233TVHEPkNxyz@gitlab.com` - this! It's so painful that nowhere it's documented,  or I just can't find it, that you should use the `oauth2` username with the token as a password.

Comment: Took me half a day to find the info but I am not working with APIs and not using oauth - just needed a simple git clone using http url with 2fa enabled for which PAT is required.

Comment: Thanks! But that only worked for me after I removed `?ref=v0.0.1` from the command