# How to perform git pull from gitlab repo with 2FA access token?

Tags: git, gitlab, two-factor-authentication

I had already cloned a few repos from gitlab and then LATER we added two factor authentication on the gitlab repos.

Now I am trying to update my local branch by doing `git pull` like this:

```
sudo git pull
```

but I get an access error like this:

```
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I have created an access token as the gitlab page [describes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) but I am never prompted to use to add my username and access token, it simply says the error message above. How do authenticate my requests?

Comment: Are you looking for [this kind of information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67534214/86072) ?

Comment: or : to update the url of your `origin` remote : `git remote set-url origin <newurl>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34917354/7976758 Replace "clone" with "pull". Better: do not use `sudo`, I'm pretty sure you don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I had to specify that I want to use http not ssh so when I used this it asked me for my username and token and it worked.

I had to add this:

```
 git pull origin-http
```